# How to add a CircularProgressIndicator on top of existing LazyColumn in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have the following screen:

```
fun ItemsScreen(
    viewModel: ItemsViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val showProgressBarState = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    if (showProgressBarState.value) { ShowProgressBar() }

    when(val resource = viewModel.state.value) {
        is Loading -> ShowProgressBar() //Works perfectly
        is Success -> LazyColumn {
            items(
                items = resource.data
            ) { item ->
                ItemCard(
                    item = item
                )
            }
            when(val r = viewModel.s.value) {
                is Loading -> showProgressBarState.value = true
                is Success -> showProgressBarState.value = false
                is Failure -> Log.d(TAG, "Failure")
            }
        }
        is Failure -> Text(
            text = r.message,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun ShowProgressBar() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        CircularProgressIndicator()
    }
}
```

The second "when" is for a delete state. I want when a item is deleted to start the progress bar. It starts but behind the LazyColumn. How to add it in front?

This is what I have in the activity class:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        Scaffold(
            //
        ) {
            ItemsScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use a Box

Comment: @AgentP I already tried and got the same behavior.

Comment: Can you post that code ? the one with the box you tried ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're updating your state value inside the view builder. It'll work in this case, but generally it's a bad practice which may lead to redundant recompositions which may slow your app. I'm talking about this part:

```
when(val r = viewModel.s.value) {
    is Loading -> showProgressBarState.value = true
    is Success -> showProgressBarState.value = false
    is Failure -> Log.d(TAG, "Failure")
}
```

You should change state using [side effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects). Here you could've use `LaunchedEffect`, so content would be called only when specified key is changed since the last recomposition.:

```
LaunchedEffect(viewModel.s.value) {
    when (val r = viewModel.s.value) {
        is Loading -> showProgressBarState.value = true
        is Success -> showProgressBarState.value = false
        is Failure -> Log.d(TAG, "Failure")
    }
}
```

But actually that was an off topic for the future, in this case you don't need `showProgressBarState` at all.

When you use `Box`, items are displayed on the screen on on top of each other. As you need to display the progress bar on top of `LazyColumn`, you need to wrap it with a `Box` and place `ShowProgressBar` after `LazyColumn`.

Also you can specify `contentAlignment = Alignment.Center` instead of wrapping `CircularProgressIndicator` with a `Column`:

```
is Resource.Success -> {
    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        LazyColumn {
            items(
                items = resource.data
            ) { item ->
                ItemCard(
                    item = item
                )
            }
        }
        when (val r = viewModel.s.value) {
            is Resource.Loading -> CircularProgressIndicator()
            is Resource.Success -> Unit
            is Resource.Failure -> Log.d(TAG, "Failure")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me again. It works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your all content into Box and also place your progressbar to top of your content.

```
Box(){
when(val resource = viewModel.state.value) {

    is Success -> LazyColumn {
    }
    is Loading -> ShowProgressBar() //move to top layer 
}
}
```