# Proper use of mutableStateflow with Launcheffect in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, kotlin-flow

Hey I am working in `MutableStateFlow` in jetpack compose. I am trying to load spinner in next screen but it's not working. I am started learning jetpack compose. I didn't find the proper way in jetpack compose. I know `MutableStateFlow` in legacy way. I'll try explain what I am trying to do and what I want to achieve. I have a **Button** in the composable function, when I press the **Button** I am going into the **viewModel** and calling the api inside `viewModelScope.launch`. On that basis I have create a class called **ResultFetchState** which is **sealed** class, inside that I used [UI state](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow#stateflow). When my api get any thing it will route to **success, error** and **loading**. The main problem is when I am using `collectAsState()` the data is going `onSuccess` but `onLoading` is not working. Hope you understand this.

**[MainActivityViewModel.kt](https://github.com/vivek-modi/SportsResult/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vivek/sportsresult/viewmodel/MainActivityViewModel.kt)**

```
class MainActivityViewModel(private val resultRepository: ResultRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val stateResultFetchState = MutableStateFlow<ResultFetchState>(ResultFetchState.OnEmpty)

    fun getSportResult() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val result = resultRepository.getSportResult()
            delay(5000)
            result.handleResult(
                onSuccess = { response ->
                    if (response != null) {
                        stateResultFetchState.value = ResultFetchState.IsLoading(false)
                        stateResultFetchState.value = ResultFetchState.OnSuccess(response)
                    } else {
                        stateResultFetchState.value = ResultFetchState.OnEmpty
                    }
                },
                onError = {
                    stateResultFetchState.value =
                        ResultFetchState.OnError(it.errorResponse?.errorMessage)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I am not adding my whole activity code. I am adding my composable function. If you need to see my whole activity click on class name below.

**[MainActivity.kt](https://github.com/vivek-modi/SportsResult/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vivek/sportsresult/ui/screen/MainActivity.kt)**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    @Composable
    fun SetupView(viewModel: MainActivityViewModel = koinViewModel()) {
        Scaffold(topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name)) },
                backgroundColor = getBackgroundColor(),
                elevation = 0.dp
            )
        }, content = { padding ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(getBackgroundColor())
                    .padding(padding),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Button(onClick = {
                    viewModel.getSportResult()
                }) {
                    Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.get_result))
                }
            }
        })
        when (val state = viewModel.stateResultFetchState.collectAsState().value) {
            is ResultFetchState.OnSuccess -> {
                logE("data >> ${state.sportResultResponse}")
            }
            is ResultFetchState.IsLoading -> {
                if (state.isLoading) {
                    logE("data loading >")
                    ResultScreen()
                }
            }
            is ResultFetchState.OnError -> {
                logE("data >> ${state.response}")
            }
            is ResultFetchState.OnEmpty -> {}
        }
    }
```

I though there is problem in my lifecycle. So I search in stack overflow of [**LaunchedEffect**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69419545/11560810) but still not working. Another question is there any use of **LaunchedEffect** in my code I am little bit confused on this side effect. My github project [link](https://github.com/vivek-modi/SportsResult). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting value of `stateResultFetchState` consecutively

```
  fun getSportResult() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val result = resultRepository.getSportResult()
            delay(5000)
            result.handleResult(
                onSuccess = { response ->
                    if (response != null) {
                        stateResultFetchState.value = ResultFetchState.IsLoading(false)
                        stateResultFetchState.value = ResultFetchState.OnSuccess(response)
                    } else {
                        stateResultFetchState.value = ResultFetchState.OnEmpty
                    }
                },
                onError = {
                    stateResultFetchState.value =
                        ResultFetchState.OnError(it.errorResponse?.errorMessage)
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

You can set to loading before getting sport results and in your ui you check if loading is true you need to set it with true

```
fun getSportResult() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        stateResultFetchState.value = ResultFetchState.IsLoading(true)
        val result = resultRepository.getSportResult()
        delay(5000)
        result.handleResult(
            onSuccess = { response ->
                if (response != null) {
                    stateResultFetchState.value = ResultFetchState.OnSuccess(response)
                } else {
                    stateResultFetchState.value = ResultFetchState.OnEmpty
                }
            },
            onError = {
                stateResultFetchState.value =
                    ResultFetchState.OnError(it.errorResponse?.errorMessage)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Also there is an issue with your UI either. Even if you correctly get loading state you might be able to see them because Scaffold places children in `content` Composable on top of each other with

```
bodyContentPlaceables.forEach {
            it.place(0, 0)
        }
```

You might need to use Composable that covers your content area as root Comopsable.

Comment: Where should I stop ui loading then?

Comment: In compose you change states. When you change your state from loading to error or success it will be removed from composition. and conditional block that is satisfied will enter composition

Comment: You can check this answer about conditional recomposition. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72705876/remember-in-composition-is-forgotten/72709495#72709495

Comment: Thats great.. Can you please also explain me what is the LaunchedEffect use ? Is there necessary in my code. I am asking because in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69419545/11560810) is using which is similar to my case I think so.

Comment: LaunchedEffect is a remember under the hood launches your code on first run or composition, then if they key or you keys you set change same as remember. block invoked based on keys. In that question you see `when(val r = viewModel.s.value)` is checked. This part runs on every time `LazyColumn` is recomposed checks state and calls correct conditional composition. But when it's already in LoadingState if it recomposed again there won't be recompositions for the Loading Composable. LaunchedEffect seems redundant in that answer.

Comment: if (showProgressBarState.value) { ShowProgressBar() } is before LazyColumn in that example that's why it doesn't show if LazyColumn is displayed. Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center){LazyColumn() when(...){Loading} is how you show a loading over your Composable based on your ui state

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246595/discussion-between-thracian-and-vivek-modi).